# Clickhouse kafka engine. Как задать интервал обращения таблицы к Kafka

Tags: clickhouse, apache-kafka

Мне необходимо настроить таблицу КХ с движком Кафки так, чтобы таблица брала данные из Кафки большими кусками, но не постоянно, а допустим, с интервалом 30 секунд или 1 минуты. Возможно ли так сделать, не нашёл параметра, отвечающего за этот интервал. Я новичок в использовании Кафки и КХ

Comment: Про КХ не знаю, как у него настроен клиент Кафки, но у Кафка консумеров есть настройка `fetch.min.bytes`, которая по умолчанию 1 байт. Если её увеличить, то можно заставить читать большими батчами.

Comment: И ещё один `fetch.max.wait.ms` - так что можно первый выкрутить в недостижимый максимум, а второй поставить как раз таким, какой тебе надо (1 минута, 30 секунд)